# overlapping clusters in R

Tags: regression, correlation, clustering

I have a bunch of observations that are correlated with each other in two different ways, so I'd like to perform logistic regressions but try to account for the correlations among observations to get the best standard errors that I can. I think I can potentially do that via overlapping clusters? E.g., if observations 1-4 relate to one subject and observations 5-8 relate to another subject, I can cluster 1-4 together and 5-8 together. But if, for example, observations 1 and 5 are correlated in some way, as are observations 2 and 6, 3 and 7, and 4 and 8, I'd want to cluster that way too (i.e., so each observation belongs to 2 clusters).

Is it possible to perform logistic regression, ideally in R but if not in some other accessible language, for data in overlapping/non-exclusive clusters? If so, how would I do it?

If I use glm and ignore the correlations, then my understanding is that the standard errors I get may be incorrect. I think gee can generally be used if I'm just looking for an average population effect, but I think that only allows me to use non-overlapping/exclusive clusters. I'm stumped for overlapping/non-exclusive clusters.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the purpose of your analysis and so it is difficult to answer. You say you want to use glm, but what for?

Comment: Sure, no problem, and thank you for reaching out. I am studying judicial decisionmaking. I have a large number of cases, each of which was heard by three judges randomly selected from a judge pool. I have whether each judge's vote was a conservative or liberal vote, and I have each judge's political affiliation. I want to see if a judge's party status predicts voting behavior. If each observation is a particular vote for a judge, then the outcome is binomial (liberal or conservative vote) and the primary predictor is the judge's political affiliation. But I think my observations ....

Comment: ... will be correlated in two ways: I have three observations for each case (because three judges vote in every case), and I have many observations for each judge. Observations for the same case are likely correlated, as are observations for each judge. I'm not sure how to model it, however. I think I have overlapping clusters? Thank you in advance for any thoughts!

Comment: @dariober, sorry still getting used to figuring out how to notify people - thanks in advance!